# Why did Shri Krishna show the whole universe to his mother?

Tags: krishna

There is a famous story related to Shri Krishna that when He was kid, he used to eat soil. One day, his mother *yashoda* caught him and asked whether he was eating soil. but Shri Krishna lied that he wasn't eating soil. To believe him, his mother asked him to open his mouth. When he opened mouth, his mother saw whole universe which made her go unconscious.

My question is why Shri Krishna showed universe in his mouth to her mother knowing that it is not a normal act to do so?

Comment: "knowing that it is not a normal act to do so" Well, that wouldn't have mattered, because he made her forget afterwards.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan seems strange to me (_as I don't know_) why showing and then making her forget later?

Comment: Well, she still gets the darshan of seeing these marvelous the things, even if the darshan isn't retained in her conscious memory.

Comment: Shri Krishna was then a toddler who was eating soil to satisfy his urge to eat. Mother Yashoda questioned Shri Krishna and asked him to open his mouth and discovered soil in his mouth. She soon realized that her duty as mother is to keep her child well fed. Her seeing the universe in her child's mouth is symbolic of her realization that her child is her universe and that she should never leave her child go hungry. This story is about a mothers remorse than about showing off by Shri Krishna.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Shri Krishna was a child He performed many pastimes just as a human child does. We all know how little children lie when they are asked if they have done something bad or wrong. So also Shri Krishna lied when mother Yashoda asked Him if He had eaten soil:

> Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa replied: My dear mother, I have never eaten dirt. All My friends complaining against Me are liars. If you think they are being truthful, you can directly look into My mouth and examine it. [SB - 10.8.35 ]

So to prove His point when He opened His mouth mother Yashoda saw the whole universe inside it. She realized the divinity of Shri Krishna and forgetting the soil eating incident, surrendered to Him mentally (SB - [10.8.41](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/10/8/41)).

However, after knowing Shri Krishna was the Lord of the universe, mother Yashoda could never have treated Him like a son and show her affection towards Him. So lord's internal potency *Yogamaya* made her forget about Shri Krishna's divinity:

> Mother Yaśodā, by the grace of the Lord, could understand the real truth. But then again, the supreme master, by the influence of the internal potency, Yoga-māyā, inspired her to become absorbed in intense maternal affection for her son. [SB - 10.8.43]
>
> Immediately forgetting Yoga-māyā’s illusion that Kṛṣṇa had shown the universal form within His mouth, mother Yaśodā took her son on her lap as before, feeling increased affection in her heart for her transcendental child. [SB - 10.8.44]

So mother Yashoda considered, loved and treated Him just as her son instead of revering Him as God even after that incident. Even if it was not a normal act to do so, **Shri Krishna performed it as a playful pastime**. Moreover, not even a minor action of Shri Krishna is normal. All His actions are divine however significant or insignificant they may seem:

> *janma karma ca me divyam* [BG - 4.9]
>   - My birth and my actions are divine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, every act of shree Krishna has a meaning.... When the kidy god Krishna ate sand which means that he can obtain anything no matter how sinned. When he opened his mouth it meant that... The whole thing he obtains is resting on him cause he is the paramatma.... But he doesn't want this to change any of the future so he made his matha unconscious but it's also been said that the one whomever is not ready to know the high superior knowledge... Will go unconscious..... It'll take a long time to give a debriefed discribtion.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers on this site need to be supported by proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500) .